# In Matlab I keep getting undefined variable or function error despite clearly defining the variable

Tags: matlab, spline

I have this piece of code in Matlab which should take an Airfoil profile and increase the number of points so that when I plot the profile in another programme I will get a smoother curve.

```
clear
%reading an external data file
fid = fopen('NACA0015.txt');
a = fscanf(fid,'%g %g',[2 inf]); % It has two rows now.
a = a';    % matrix transpose

n = input('200')      %e.g., n=35

for i=1:n
    for j=1:2
      fprintf('%12.7f',a(i,j)); %a(i,1) is first column, a(i,2) is 2nd col
    end
    fprintf('\n');
end
fclose(fid);

for i=1:n
    x(i)=a(i,1);      %x , y vectors
    y(i)=a(i,2);
end

% use spline to create more points

xx=0:0.01:1      % e.g., step =0.01 (number of points = (1-0)/0.01=100)
yy = spline(x,y,xx);      % xx and yy are new generated values of Naca0012

fprintf('\n print spline values \n');

plot(xx,yy,'ro')    
hold on
plot(x,y,'*')
```

When I run this I get the error

Undefined function or variable 'x'.

Error in reading_external_data_and_spline (line 26)
yy = spline(x,y,xx);      % xx and yy are new generated values of Naca0012

I am at a complete loss as to why this is not working when the x variable is clearly defined in the code, please could someone help me with this

Comment: I'm guessing that `n` is `0` and therefore the loop that creates `x` never gets run since `1:0` yields an empty array.

Comment: Additionally, if you hit enter without providing an input, `input` returns an empty matrix. Trying to iterate from `1:[]` means that `x` will never be initialized, same as `1:(any number less than 1)`.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue because when I run it, it shows 200 in the command console and then I press enter so the input has been provided

Comment: But if you set a breakpoint after that line and look at the value of `n`, what do you get?

Answer (score 3):

It's how you're using [`input`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html). The argument in `input` isn't the default value, it's the prompt text. If you type the command into the console and hit enter, you get this:

```
>> n = input('200')
200

n =

     []

>>
```

Input doesn't accept a default. If you really want to have an interactive prompt with a default answer, you want [`inputdlg`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputdlg.html):

```
answer = inputdlg('Enter a number of lines to parse', 'n', 1, '200');
n = str2double(answer);
```

note that `inputdlg` returns text always, so you need to convert to a number.